# "PostgreSQL Error: relation "table_name" does not exist" When trying to SELECT * FROM "table_name"

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I am trying to run a simple script on a simple PostgreSQL database with one table. When I use `db.query('SELECT * FROM groups')`

I get the error `ERROR:  relation "groups" does not exist at character 15`

I ran the SQL in a Postgresql sandbox and it worked fine when I selected *, so I don't know what the problem here is. Here is the SQL Code

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups;

CREATE TABLE groups (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    birthPlace varchar(255) NOT NULL; );

INSERT INTO groups (name, birthPlace) VALUES
    ( 'Marco', 'Italy' ),
    ( 'Callum', 'Scotland' ),
    ( 'Bob, Ireland' );
```

And this is the javascript code where I use db.query

```js
const db = require ('../dbConfig')

class Groups {
    constructor(data){
        this.id = data.id
        this.name = data.name
        this.birthPlace = data.birthPlace
    }

        static get all() {
            return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) => {
                try {
                    const groupData = await db.query('SELECT * FROM groups;')
                    const groups = groupData.rows.map(d => new Groups(d))
                    resolve(groups);
                } catch (err) {
                    reject("Error retrieving groups")
                }
            })
        }
   }  
module.exports = Groups;
```

I have read that this error can arise when quotes or capitals were used when the table is created but I haven't used either anywhere in my code. I hope these code snippets suffice, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try including the schema name in the Select ?

Comment: As in 'SELECT * FROM public.groups' ? I just tried that and it didn't work, I got the same error

Comment: yeah assuming the table is in public.! And you're definitely in the correct database? SELECT current_database() to get the database name & SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' to see the tables

Comment: I got it to work, looks like all I needed to do was remove all orphans, volumes and then prune